# What is the number $A$? And the function $G$?

Tags: proof-verification, riemann-zeta

In one of my screenshots I found the following equality :

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n+4}{n(n^2+3n+2)2^{n+2}}\left(n-\sum\limits_{k=2}^n\zeta(n)\right)=\frac{3\ln(A)}{2}+\frac{\gamma}8+\frac{19}{48}-\frac{19\ln(2)}{24}-\frac{\ln(\pi)}{4}$$

with no explanation of what $A$ is.

**Is A a known number ? If not, what does it equal here ?** (I do not have the proof of the above, nor can I prove it myself, and therefore I can't find $A$ myself)

---

Edit :

I just found the generalisation $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n(1-x)+2}{n(n+1)(n+2)}x^{n+1}\left(n-\sum\limits_{k=2}^n\zeta(n)\right)$$
    $$=\ln(\Gamma(2-x))+\frac{3-\log(2\pi)}{2}x+\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}-1\right)x^2+\frac{x^3}{6}-x\ln(\Gamma(2-x))-\ln(G(2-x))$$

That might help in finding $A$ (i didn't manage to do it myself), but also raises another question for me : **what is the function $G$** ?

Comment: it seems A is 4 ! but i'm not sure !

Comment: @bluebird7 How did you get that ?

Comment: $G(z)$ is most likely [Barnes G-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function) and $A \approx 1.2824271291$ is the [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant).

Comment: There is a typo in your first expression, the denominator in the LHS should be $\color{red}{n}(n^2+3n+2)2^{n+2}$. If you fix that, the value of $A$ in the RHS will be numerically matching the value of Glaisher-Kinkelin constant I gave in previous comment.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks. You can post that as answer :)

Comment: The first expression can be obtained form the generalization by fixing $x$ to $1/2$ and using the fact $\displaystyle\;G(3/2) =  \frac{\sqrt[24]{2 e^3 \pi^6}}{A^{3/2}}\;$ (ref: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=BarnesG%283%2F2%29))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $G(z)$ in the generalization is the [Barnes G function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function) and $A$ in the first expression is the [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant). Numerically${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$,

$$A \approx 1.282427129100622636875342568869791727767688927325001192063740\ldots$$

One can obtain the first expression from the generalization by fixing $x$ to $1/2$ 
and using following value of $G(z)$ at $z = \frac32$ ${}^{\color{blue}{[2]}}$.
$$G\left(\frac32\right) = \frac{\sqrt[24]{2 e^3 \pi^6}}{A^{3/2}}$$

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - [Glaisher Kinkelin constant](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Glaisher+Kinkelin+constant) from WA.
- $\color{blue}{[2]}$ - [$G(3/2)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=BarnesG[3%2F2]) from WA.